как подключать многоразовые html компоненты?
Допустим, что у нас есть 5 страниц и на каждой из них одинаковые header, footer и карточки.
Как лучше всего подключать отдельные html файлы в 2024году?

как и в 2023 году - никак. нет таких средств в html.

А есть какие ни будь инструменты в gulp для этой задачи? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Ну используйте тогда pug какой-нибудь или handlebars

Есть еще вариант с тем, чтобы реализовать single-page-application. Или, как вариант - сделать страницу с футером, хэдером и т.д. и с помощью JS подменять контент. Но лучше воспользоваться чем-нибудь типа react для таких целей

из средств встроенных именно в сам html <iframe> предпочтительнее, но можно и <object> попробовать. для замены содержимого фрейма можно ссылки на него нацелить: <a href='index.html' TARGET='iframe_id'>. эдак в нулевых это было обычным делом, а щас js фреймворки использовать моднее.

Есть две группы инструментов которые реализуют использование отдельных компонентов - это шаблонизаторов и фреймворки с поддержкой такой функциональности.
Шаблонизаторы:

Mustache
Handlebars
Pug

Фреймворки:

React
Vue
Angular


Если вы говорите про нативную поддержку прямо в html, то её нет.

Так-же существует множество фрйемворков для генерации страниц из модулей на бэкенде, например:

Blazor (C#)
Django (Python)
Ruby on Rails (Ruby)
Laravel (PHP)
Express.js (node.js)


Ну и серверные уж перечислите на php, python, node.js

Большое спасибо! А какой шаблонизатор вы используете или порекомендовали бы использовать?

@SwaD дело сделано

@SvyaT_T из всего зоопарка пользовался только Angular, потому что он до этого использовался в команде. А по сравнениям не подскажу.

Можно использовать SSI.
Для поддержки работы именно в html (не в shtml) нужно немного изменить конфигурацию сервера.
Но лучше начать изучать хотя бы php.

Для JS я использую плагин Gulp Rigger:
.pipe(rigger())

"use" (документация: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rigger)
//= components/footerSpoiler.js
    

Для HTML я использую плагин gulp Panini:
.pipe(panini({
   root: srcPath,
   layouts: srcPath + "template/layouts/",
   partials: srcPath + "template/partials/",
   data: srcPath + "template/data/"
}))

"use" (документация: https://www.npmjs.com/package/panini)
---
layout: default
title: Catalog
icon: assets/images/heart-like.svg
style: assets/css/catalog-style.min.css
js: assets/js/indexJS.min.js
---
<div class="wrapper">
   {{> header }}
   
   {{> footer }}
</div>

